# How to store a value and change it when it is updated in python?

Tags: python, bitcoin

So I'm trying to create a bitcoin price tracker and with it, it will tell you whether the price went up or down. For example, when you start it, it shows the price and an increase of $0.00, then when it increases or decreases it shows that. The problem is after it tests again, it reverts back to 0, not staying at the increase or decrease amount.

Heres what I have tried and everything works but when it changes, it only shows it until it tests for a change, after one second.

```py
###############
import requests
import time
import os
#############

#######
bct = 0.0
bctChange = 0
errorLevel = 0
################
os.system('cls')
################

#print('The current price of Bitcoin is $10,000.00')
#print('Connected: True')
#print('Increase of $2.50') #use abs() for absolute value
#print('ErrorLevel: 0')
#print('ErrorLevel is the amount of request errors\nthere have been to the bitcoin api')

########################
def place_value(number): 
    return ("{:,}".format(number)) 
#####################################################################
r = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
bctPriceStart = place_value(round(r.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate_float'], 2))
###########################################################################

while True:
  try:
    #############
    bctLast = bct
    #####################################################################
    r = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
    bct = round(r.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate_float'], 2)
    ####################################################
    if (bctChange != bctChange):
      bctChange = bctLast - bct
    ###########################

    ################
    os.system('cls')
    print('The current price of Bitcoin is $' + place_value(bct))
    #############################################################

    #################
    if (bctLast > 0):
      print('Increase of $' + place_value(abs(round(bctChange, 2))))
      time.sleep(1)
    ###############

    ###################
    elif (bctLast < 0):
      print('Decrease of $' + place_value(abs(round(bctChange, 2))))
      time.sleep(1)
    ###############


  except requests.ConnectionError or requests.ConnectTimeout or requests.HTTPError or requests.NullHandler or requests.ReadTimeout or requests.RequestException or requests.RequestsDependencyWarning or requests.Timeout or requests.TooManyRedirects:
    #Do error function
    os.system('cls')
    print('There was an error...')
```

Comment: Remove `if (bctChange != bctChange):`.  Also, it should be `bctChange = bct - bctLast`. Then add towards the bottom: `else: time.sleep(1)`

Comment: One thing I would recommend: this- `###############` is incredibly un-pythonic, and makes the code hard to read.

Comment: Also, you don't need the () around your if statements

Comment: I removed the if ```(bctChange != bctChange):``` Changed the ```bctChange = bct - bctLast```. And added the ```else: time.sleep(1)``` But it didn't work. It only shows the increase or decreases for a second before clearing it. And I removed the ```######```'s and the () in my if statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, replacing your script with this should work:

```
import requests
import time

bct = 0.0
bctChange = 0

def place_value(number): 
    return ("{:,}".format(number)) 

r = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
bct = round(r.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate_float'], 2)
print('The starting price of Bitcoin is $' + place_value(bct))

while True:
    try:
        bctLast = bct
        r = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
        bct = round(r.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate_float'], 2)
        bctChange = bctLast - bct
        if bctChange > 0:
            print('The current price of Bitcoin is $' + place_value(bct))
            print('Increase of $' + place_value(abs(round(bctChange, 2))))
        elif bctChange < 0:
            print('The current price of Bitcoin is $' + place_value(bct))
            print('Decrease of $' + place_value(abs(round(bctChange, 2))))
        time.sleep(1)

    except requests.ConnectionError or requests.ConnectTimeout or requests.HTTPError or requests.NullHandler or requests.ReadTimeout or requests.RequestException or requests.RequestsDependencyWarning or requests.Timeout or requests.TooManyRedirects:
      print('There was an error...')
```

The problem is your `if...elif` statements were based on `btcLast` not `btcChange`, and you don't need the `if` statement around `bctChange = bctLast - bct`. You were also calling `os.system('cls')` which was clearing your printed output rather than printing it persistently.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. All it did was show the current price for one second before clearing it and it wouldn't show again.

Comment: have updated the formatting. This returns the expected behaviour when I run it. It's not entirely clear what your expected result is. I've also updated it so it only prints the price if it changes. Could you clarify what you're trying to do? Do you mean if you stop and start the script again?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm trying to make it always show the increase/decrease in the price. The problem is it will show it but not stay shown, it clears after 1 second

Comment: You did what? It may be because you have all those calls to `os.system('cls')`. Have you rerun the script as written above (with these removed)? It works now.

Comment: I copied your code and replaced mine with it... I'm calling the os.system('cls') to make it auto-update and not have everything printed out, only have the current price along with the increase.

EDIT: I just added the os.system('cls') and everything works now

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean but I'm glad it's working. Perhaps you could clarify your question so it's clearer what was wrong. It would be more helpful for other people if you did.